# Module that can help control excel from within python application anything more needed than pywin32?

Tags: python, excel, wxpython

I have a viewer I built using WXPython.  The viewer is basically a browser (built on IE wx.lib.iewin) that loads the txt or htm files I have in a directory and then lets me move through the files sequentially.  Instead of having to go to the directory to select the next file to view the viewer/browser has a next button that loads the next file in the queue.

I want to be able to add a new feature that allows me to highlight some text that is visible in the browser and then push a button and have that text passed into a cell in excel.

Lots of things are going to have to happen like I need to be able to find and start a new instance of excel.  I need to be able to add a new worksheet and pass some values to populate cells on the worksheet based on the file I am looking at and then if I want to collect some data from the file I want to be able to highlight the data in the viewer and then press a button on the viewer and have the data passed to excel.

I think I am going to start with PyWin32 but I am wondering if there is something else I need but I don't know enough to look for it.

If someone knows of an example where text was piped from a Python application to excel under the users control I would appreciate a pointer in that direction.  It is easy enough I think to do this going from the application to a file that gets created (but not displayed) but I am hoping to go from the browser to the excel file so that the user can evaluate their work in progress.

Comment: Well, you need the documentation for the Excel scripting model. If you know how to read VBA/VB.NET (and internally translate to Python), the built-in Excel documentation should be sufficient for that. Otherwise, PyWin32 has everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recomend using one of the python excel modules like python-excel.
It works on any OS, and without any other Excel application installed.

http://www.python-excel.org/

Code would look somehting liek this to write to a new xls document, slightly different to open an existing.

```
import xlwt
wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('sheet 1')
# indexing is zero based, row then column
sheet.write(0,1,'test text')
wbk.save('test.xls')
```

Hopefully this can get you on the right path, then you'll be able to post more specific questions if you run into problems.

Note: Another option is openpyxl:

http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/tutorial.html

Comment: It sounds like the user wants to interact with the running copy of Excel (paste text into the current cell), which means your answers don't actually help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using wxPython (which I assume you are due to the tag), you should look at XLSGrid: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/08/20/wxpython-new-widget-announced-xlsgrid/

If you just want to work with Excel, I would recommend [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) or [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd), although you can use PyWin32 to work with it too via COM: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/16/python-and-microsoft-office-using-pywin32/